# Ruby multiple group_by of array

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an array like this:

```
[{:a=>"2017-01-01", :b=>"2", :c=>"1"}, {:a=>"2017-01-01", :b=>"2", :c=>"2"}, {:a=>"2017-01-02", :b=>"5", :c=>"1"}]
```

If, for example, I group the array with the key ":a", the result is:

```
p = y.group_by { |g| g[:a]}

 => {"2017-01-01"=>[{:a=>"2017-01-01", :b=>"2", :c=>"1"}, {:a=>"2017-01-01", :b=>"2", :c=>"2"}], "2017-01-02"=>[{:a=>"2017-01-02", :b=>"5", :c=>"1"}]}
```

Now I want to group for each ":a" the key ":b" like:

```
 => {"2017-01-01"=>["2" => [{:a => "2017-01-01", :b => "2", :c => "1" }], ... }
```

How can I do? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**:

multiple group by ... 1° group_by a, 2° group_by b the result of 1°, etc..

```
y.group_by {|g| g[:a]}.map do |k,v|
 [
  k, v.group_by { |d| d[:b] }.map do |p,q|
   [p, q.group_by { |f| f[:c] }]
  end.to_h
 ]
end.to_h
```

Comment: 1. `[:a=>...` is not a valid Ruby object. Please edit to correct. 2. It's not obvious what `...` stands for. Please replace all `...` with the values you desire as output for the example. 3. When you give an example (generally) assign a variable to each input object (e.g., `arr = [{:a=>...`) so that readers can refer to those variables (here just one) in answers and comments without having to define them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick answer, using your code above:

```
y = [{:a=>"2017-01-01", :b=>"2", :c=>"1"}, {:a=>"2017-01-01", :b=>"2", :c=>"2"}, {:a=>"2017-01-02", :b=>"5", :c=>"1"}]
p = y.group_by { |g| g[:a]}
q = p.map {|date, list| [date, list.group_by {|g| g[:b]}]}.to_h
```

This gives the desired result of:

```
q == {
  "2017-01-01" => {
    "2"=> [
      {:a=>"2017-01-01", :b=>"2", :c=>"1"},
      {:a=>"2017-01-01", :b=>"2", :c=>"2"}
    ]
  },
  "2017-01-02" => {
    "5"=> [
      {:a=>"2017-01-02", :b=>"5", :c=>"1"}
    ]
  }
}
```

This slightly odd pattern of mapping the hash to a list of arrays, then converting it back to a hash (using `to_h`) can be simplified slightly if you are working with a [Rails v4.2+ project](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#notable-changes), by use of [`Hash#transform_values`](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/transform_values):

```
p.transform_values {|list| list.group_by {|g| g[:b]}}
```

However with that said, it is generally considered bad practice to be manipulating complex, nested hash objects like this. If your code gets too complicated, you may wish to consider redesigning how it works, in a more Object-Oriented manner.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: I would submit to you another question. If I want to add an additional group_by the second filter, how do I proceed?

Comment: An additional `group_by`? Do you mean for a final result like: `{"2017-01-01" => { "2"=> {"1" => {:a=>"2017-01-01", :b=>"2", :c=>"1"} ....`??

Comment: Yes, I would an additional grop_by... I found this solution `y.group_by {|g| g[:a]}.map do |k,v|
    [
     k, v.group_by { |d| d[:b] }.map do |p,q|
      [p, q.group_by { |f| f[:c] }]
     end.to_h
    ]
   end.to_h
`

Comment: Erm... Yes, something like that would work. But please, do note my above comment: *"...bad practice to be manipulating complex, nested hash objects... consider redesigning how it works..."*. There are better ways of handling complex data structures in ruby than big nested hashes!

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: It's not premature to write things in an object-oriented way, when using an object-oriented language ;) I'd need to see the "bigger picture" (context) here in order to properly suggest a better design pattern.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135372/discussion-between-domenico-garofoli-and-tom-lord).

Comment: Good news! `Hash#transform_values` is available in Core Ruby from 2.4 onwards,
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values

Answer (score 3):

I think, a few from possible solutions is:

```
 y = [
  {
    :a=>"2017-01-01", 
    :b=>"2", 
    :c=>"1"
  }, 
  {
    :a=>"2017-01-01", 
    :b=>"2", 
    :c=>"2"
  }, 
  {
    :a=>"2017-01-02", 
    :b=>"5", 
    :c=>"1"
  }
]
```

first:

```
y.group_by { |g| [g[:a], g[:b]] }
```

but result would seems:

```
#=> {["2017-01-01", "2"]=>[{:a=>"2017-01-01", :b=>"2", :c=>"1"}, {:a=>"2017-01-01", :b=>"2", :c=>"2"}], ["2017-01-02", "5"]=>[{:a=>"2017-01-02", :b=>"5", :c=>"1"}]}
```

and second one:

```
y.group_by { |g| g[:a] }.map do |key, value| 
   [key, value.group_by { |g| g[:b] }] 
end.to_h

#=> {"2017-01-01"=>{"2"=>[{:a=>"2017-01-01", :b=>"2", :c=>"1"}, {:a=>"2017-01-01", :b=>"2", :c=>"2"}]}, "2017-01-02"=>{"5"=>[{:a=>"2017-01-02", :b=>"5", :c=>"1"}]}}
```